# Returning a string from a if-statement and for-loop

Tags: java, string, if-statement, for-loop, return

I have the following code and instead of using the System.out.println() method, I need to instead return a string that includes stars and minuses in the same way that the code below does.

Essentially, instead of just returning the "" at the end, I need the stars and minuses to be included in the actual return string itself!

I am very new to Java and have no idea of how to do this.

I would appreciate any advice.

```
public static String starMinusLine(int stars, int minuses){

            if(minuses ==1){
            for (int j= 0; j< stars; ++j){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < (minuses); ++i){
                System.out.print("-");
            }
        }

            if (minuses % 2 == 0){
            for (int i = 0; i < (minuses*0.5); ++i){
                System.out.print("-");
            }
            for (int j= 0; j< stars; ++j){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            for (int k=0; k < (minuses*0.5); ++k){
                System.out.print("-");
            }
        }
            if (minuses % 2 == 1 && minuses != 1){
            for (int i = 0; i < ((minuses*0.5)-0.5); ++i){
                System.out.print("-");
            }
            for (int j= 0; j< stars; ++j){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            for (int k=0; k < ((minuses*0.5)); ++k){
                System.out.print("-");
            }   
        }
        return "";  
    }
```

Comment: use a `StringBuilder` to append the output and return `StringBuilder.toString()` at the end.

Comment: Sometimes, when you are a beginner, it can be hard to find the relevant API because you don't know what words to search for. Hopefully, with the `StringBuilder` hint, the OP will post his own answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use StringBuilder to build up the string as you go:

```
    public static String starMinusLine(int stars, int minuses) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        if (minuses == 1) {
            for (int j = 0; j < stars; ++j) {
                sb.append("*");
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < (minuses); ++i) {
                sb.append("-");
            }
        }

        if (minuses % 2 == 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < (minuses * 0.5); ++i) {
                sb.append("-");
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < stars; ++j) {
                sb.append("*");
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < (minuses * 0.5); ++k) {
                sb.append("-");
            }
        }
        if (minuses % 2 == 1 && minuses != 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ((minuses * 0.5) - 0.5); ++i) {
                sb.append("-");
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < stars; ++j) {
                sb.append("*");
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < ((minuses * 0.5)); ++k) {
                sb.append("-");
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't even know about the StringBuilder method! Thank you for this.